# How to retain first and last line and remove in between in logfile

Tags: regex, perl

I'm running several spark jobs which produces like log below when the job is waiting for resources.

```
22/01/03 14:42:25 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:27 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:29 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:31 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:33 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:35 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:37 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:39 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
```

After the job completes, I want to reduce the log file size by removing the redundant msgs by executing some perl command. I want the output like below with first and last line alone.

```
22/01/03 14:42:25 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:39 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
```

I tried something like below but since the timestamp is changing, I'm not able to use the greedy operator.

```
perl -0777 -ne ' { s/(^\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d \d\d:.+? Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again.)+/$1/mg;print } ' log-file.
```

In actual scenario, the log section could repeat multiple times. Something like this.

```
sometext1
sometext2
22/01/03 14:42:25 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:27 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:29 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:31 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:33 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:35 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:37 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:39 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
sometext3
sometext4
22/01/03 14:42:49 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:51 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:51 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:51 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:53 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
sometext5
sometext6
```

Can this be solved using regex?

Required output:

```
sometext1
sometext2
22/01/03 14:42:25 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:39 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
sometext3
sometext4
22/01/03 14:42:49 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:53 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
sometext5
sometext6
```

Comment: You can try something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/fZWwY3/1) or [this](https://regex101.com/r/fZWwY3/2). Substitute each macth with contents of group 1 followed by contents of group 2. [CODE](https://regex101.com/r/fZWwY3/1/codegen?language=perl)

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh the timestamp in second line is missing.. need that for computing wait time later

Comment: Fixed [here](https://regex101.com/r/fZWwY3/4)

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh.. thanks for trying. Still the boundry scenario is missed, what if the job is ran on midnight and timestamp changes from 22/01/03 to 22/01/04

Comment: It will still work...see [here](https://regex101.com/r/fZWwY3/5). What is the expected match for such a boundary case?

Comment: *Can this be solved using regex?* Why do you want to solve it with a regex? Isn't that just imposing arbitrary restrictions on yourself? Is this a purely academic question?

Comment: @TLP.. ok any other solution is also welcome.. I overlooked the problem, I thought it can be solved using a one-liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using a regex may be possible, this can easily be solved with normal Perl code. I think the code is clearer and easier to maintain. I added 3 lines to your sample input to test for the edge case that we end on a line which matches our search.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# This string can be replaced as needed
my $str = "INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again";

my ($first, $last);

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/\Q$str/) {                      # if pattern matches current line
        if ($first) {                    # if this is an "in between" line
            $last = $_;                  # save line and go next
        } else {                         # if this is the first line
            print if not eof;            # print it..
            $first = $_;                 # ...save line and go next
        }
        print if eof;                    # print last line to avoid edge cases
    } elsif ($first && $last) {          # $str didn't match: finished a range of lines
        print $last, $_;                 # print and reset
        $first = undef;
        $last = undef;
    } else {
        print;                           # print everything else
    }
}

__DATA__
sometext1
sometext2
22/01/03 14:42:25 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:27 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:29 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:31 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:33 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:35 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:37 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:39 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
sometext3
sometext4
22/01/03 14:42:49 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:51 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:51 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:51 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:53 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
sometext5
sometext6
22/01/03 14:42:49 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:51 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:51 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
```

Output:

```
sometext1
sometext2
22/01/03 14:42:25 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:39 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
sometext3
sometext4
22/01/03 14:42:49 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:53 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
sometext5
sometext6
22/01/03 14:42:49 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:51 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
```

Comment: hey @TLP, thank you so much.. yes script is better than one-liner..

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex:

```
^(\d{2}(?:\/\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}(.*$)\s*)(\d{2}(?:\/\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}\2\s*)+
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZWwY3/4)

---

**Explanation:**

- `^` - matches the start of a line
- `(\d{2}(?:\/\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}(.*$)\s*)` - First log line is stored as **group 1**

  - `(\d{2}(?:\/\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}` - matches the pattern of format `XX/XX/XX XX:XX:XX` where `X` is a digit
  - `(.*$)` - matches everything until the end of the line. Whatever is matched is stored in **Group 2**. The actual log(without the timestamp) is stored in this group.
  - `\s*` - matches 0 or more whitespaces
- `(\d{2}(?:\/\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}\2\s*)+` - matches all the remaining continuous log lines starting with the format `XX/XX/XX XX:XX:XX` followed by contents of group 2 but only the last such log line will be stored in **group 3**

Now, replace each match with contents of group 1 followed by group 3 `$1$3`

Comment: can you refine further for the boundary scenario

Comment: Works for the boundary scenario as well where there is a change in date, This works irrespective of any date entered - check [here](https://regex101.com/r/fZWwY3/5). If the expected output for such a case is different, pls edit the question and mention the output for such a case

Answer (score 2):

A regex solution

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

die "Usage: $0 file\n" if not @ARGV;

my $fc = do { local $/; <> };  # file content

my $d2 = qr{[0-9]{2}};
my $ts = qr{$d2/$d2/$d2 $d2:$d2:$d2};

$fc =~ s{ ($ts\s*(.*?)\n) (?: $ts\s*\g{-1}\n )+ ( $ts\s*\g{-2}\n ) }{$1$3}gx;

say $fc;
```

It matches a timestamp, then the rest of the line. Then, a non-capturing group timestamp + what-it-last-captured<sup>†</sup> is matched as many times as possible up to another such pattern, since we need the first and the last while timestamps differ.  It stops at any other text. Then it repeates, by `/g`.

Another way to retain the first-and-last lines in each group is to capture *inside* the non-capturing group, and use that in the replacement as it'll be the last such pattern in the group of lines

```
$fc =~ s{ ($ts\s*(.*?)\n) (?: ($ts\s*\g{2}\n) )+ }{$1$3}gx;
```

Now we need to count for our backreference with `\g{2}`, not use a relative one.

Both variants above produce the desired output with the given input

```
sometext1
sometext2
22/01/03 14:42:25 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:39 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
sometext3
sometext4
22/01/03 14:42:49 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
22/01/03 14:42:53 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
sometext5
sometext6
```

This wasn't tested for possible weird input or edge cases, other than for the one provided in [TLP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70744548/4653379) (thanks TLP), but I don't expect surprises. Please report if there's unexpected behavior.

This can be squeezed into an one-liner, if for some reason that's required.

---

<sup>†</sup>  Via a [relative backreference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Capture-groups), `\g{-1}`